# Is it countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Show that the set of all bit strings (strings of 0’s and 1’s) is countable.

Would you start by making a grid? I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

This is correct only if we by "string" mean something with *finite* length.

You would prove it by listing them all. First list all zero-length strings. Then list all strings of length one. Then all those of length two, and so on.

Concatenate all the finite lists.

Answer (score 2):

We define a bijection $\varphi$ from the set $\mathbb{S}$ of bit strings to the set $\mathbb{P}$ of positive integers.

Given any bit string $s$, first form the bit string $1s$. Let $\varphi(s)$ be the positive integer with binary representation $1s$. For example. $\varphi(001)$ is the number with binary representation $1001$, that is, $9$.

Note that the *empty string* is an element of $\mathbb{S}$. It is mapped to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you want the set of all finite length bit strings.  How many $10$ bit strings are there?  How many $n$ bit strings.  The counts of strings are distinct, so add them up.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the following:

A bit-string of length $N$ can be represented by a number $n < 2^{N+1}$.
As an enumeration order you can then use
$0,1,0,1,2,3,0,\ldots, 7,0, \ldots$ where all blocks are $0$-padded from the left to fit the respective length. i.e.
$$0, 1, 00, 01, 10, 11, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111, 0000, \ldots$$